# GCS and PCS data misalignment in ArcMap when zoomed in

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system

I have a shapefile in NAD83 UTM18 which I need to get into GCS NAD83. I tried both loading it into an empty GCS NAD83 feature class directly and the "project" tool. The results are the same - the source and the converted line up perfectly until zoomed in to a large scale (such as 1:3) when misalignment between the two can be seen consistently. This happens regardless of whether the data frame is set to GCS or PCS.

Is this a display issue, or due to insufficient accuracy of the on the fly conversion? Or maybe there are more complex reasons?

Comment: What's the mismatch if you measure the differences with the measure tool? Also, you might try loading the original shapefile into a fc, then projecting it. Or keeping the output as a shapefile as well. Still see a mismatch?

Comment: It is ~0.01 ft. I tried loading shape into fc with same PCS then reprojecting and it seems to do the trick. However I noticed in doing so another difference is the projected fc took on a default resolution of 0.000000001 dd, which is finer than that of my original test DB, which had a resolution of 0.000000784415 dd per the spec for the project. So I did another direct loading test using the finer resolution which didn't exhibit the misalignment. Therefore I think it is likely related to the spatial resolution. Either way it is small and not a real concern, however I'm intrigued. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing experiment prompted by mkennedy I found the degree of discrepancy is tied to the spatial resolution of the target layer (and similarly inferred that of the original feature class plays a role as well).